# System sending SIGTERM and SIGKILL during normal work

Tags: linux, signals, multithreading

I have a program (C++) that works with TCP sockets in multithreaded manner. The multithreading is intensive, about 100 threads (POSIX threads).

Sometimes, not quite sure when, the program gets terminated by `SIGTERM`. After some googling I found out that it is not normal for system to send `SIGTERM`. I've decided to look what happens if I ignore the signal. Now the system sends `SIGKILL`. I assume it tries with `SIGTERM` and when the application does not terminate, the system kills it.

I have tried running it in gdb, and got no signals.

I've run it in valgrind, no signals. No valgrind errors either. Memory consumption was normal, it seems I have no memory leaks. Upon exit it had 7Mb heap in use.

Nothing suspicious in `/var/log/messages, /var/log/syslogd`.

The system is Debian 2.6.32-5.

Basically, the question is why may the system send `SIGTERM` followed by `SIGKILL` to an arbitrary process? And how can I stop at that point to see what happens (gdb alters the behavior).

Comment: Since you're needing C++ debugging help, this is really a programming question.  I've flagged it for migration to SO.

Comment: @depquid He's got a program receiving unexpected signals; that doesn't seem like a C++ problem

Comment: @MichaelMrozek You're right; when I first read it, I was focused on the debugging aspects (valgrind, gdb) and that made me think "coding".

Answer (score 4):

'system' is a very ambiguous term. If we're talking the kernel, the kernel will never send a SIGTERM. It will send SIGKILL when the OOM killer is invoked though.

The likely scenario is a script or something which has a bad `pkill` or `killall` command that is inappropriately matching your process. When you launch the command with `gdb`, it's process name & arguments are different, so it would look different to the `pkill`/`killall`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have renamed the file to `1`, and it got killed. I have also created a `while(1) sleep(1);` process with the name it had before, put it in the same folder and it was not killed. Both processes had no arguments. So I assume it's not the process name.

Comment: @Aneri interesting. At this point options are limited. If you have selinux available, I would try creating a selinux policy to log when any application sends a signal. This way you can figure out where it's coming from. Or add something to LD_PRELOAD (for the entire system) to override `kill()` and log when it's called.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have created a file with a logging version of `kill()`, but it has shown no kill of my pid! It does log kills, I've tested it and saw `udevd` killing some processes and so on. But nothing killed my program. I had my lib in `/etc/ld.so.preload`, so it was active for the entire system. I do not know how to set the policy for selinux, but will try to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a systemtap script and monitor signal delivery. The simplest approach which may be sufficient is e.g. here: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/lwtools/killsnoop-nd.stp

Can be extended to e.g. print the entire process tree of the killer.

A better script would not monitor the syscall, but the place where the signal is actually delivered. Coming up with such a script is left as an exercise for the reader.